# Jquery - After .append, .hover on other element not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, appendchild

I wrote a bit of code to handle the insertion of a comment via AJAX.
Once you have entered the comment, having received the HTML from the server and use `.append()` to insert it into the DOM, does not seem to be handled the event `.hover()` for the new item.

**There is the code:**

```
/**
 * This code manage insert comment with ajax
 **/

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('form[id^=insert_comment_for_product_]').submit(function (event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();

        var productId = $(this).attr('id');
        var productIdClear = productId.substr(productId.lastIndexOf('_', 0) - 1, productId.length);

        var textarea = $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' textarea').val();
        var textareaId = $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' textarea').attr('id');
        var token = $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' input#user_comment_product__token').val();

        var gif = $(this).parent('div').children('img.insert_comment_img');
        $(gif).show();

        $.post($(this).attr('action'),
        {
            'id': productIdClear.toString(),
            'user_comment_product[comment]': textarea,
            'user_comment_product[_token]' : token
        },
        function(data) 
        {
            $('div.product_comment>div').append(data);
            $('#' + textareaId).val(' ');
            $(gif).hide();
        });

    });
   /**
    * This is the function that no work afert .append()
    **/


    $('div.comment[id^=comment_]').hover(function()
    {
        var commentId = $(this).attr('id');

        $('#' + commentId + ' img.comment_delete').show();

        $('#' + commentId + ' img.comment_delete').click(function(event)
        {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            commentId = commentId.substr(commentId.lastIndexOf('_') + 1, commentId.length);

            $.post("../../../user/comment/delete",
            {
                'id': commentId.toString()
            },
            function(data) 
            {
                if(data.responseCode == 200)
                {
                    $('div#comment_' + commentId).hide();
                }
            });
        })

    },
    function ()
    {
        var commentId = $(this).attr('id');

        $('#' + commentId + ' img.comment_delete').hide();
    });
});
```

**WHY?**

Comment: Why? Because `$('div.comment[id^=comment_]').hover(...` only binds a hover handler to elements matching that selector _at that moment,_ not for elements that might match it in future.

Comment: @nnnnnn How i can match `$('div.comment[id^=comment_]').hover(...` after `.append()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `on` function to bind to elements that are dynamically added so instead of this:

```
$('div.comment[id^=comment_]').hover(function()
```

do this:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', 'div.comment[id^=comment_]', function(e) {
    // code from mouseover hover function goes here
});

$(document).on('mouseout', 'div.comment[id^=comment_]', function(e) {
     // code from mouseout hover function goes here
});
```

Comment: But the OP's code calls `.hover()` with two callbacks (one for mouseenter and one for mouseleave). And `.on()`'s support for the string `'hover'` was removed in v1.9.

Comment: @nnnnnn My mistake, here's an update that should work a little better.

Comment: Yep, that's more like it clav. +1, though I'd suggest trying `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` rather than `mouseover` and `mouseout` for a closer match to what `.hover()` does.

Answer (score 1):

.hover() is bound before your append happens, so the event isn't on the item. 
You need to use .on() for both mouseenter and mouseleave in order for it to work.
See the 'Additional Notes' section on here: http://api.jquery.com/on/